# Native elements in typescript

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, renderer

I am working on a carousel but it is using jQuery, and use of jQuery is discouraged with angular2, although using of jQuery is not working out with dynamic content for me while it works with static images and content.

Here is jQuery code for slider carousel:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 10000
})
$('.fdi-Carousel .item').each(function () {
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    if (next.next().length > 0) {
        next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
    else {
        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

it is not working with dynamic content, don't know what is the problem cause it is working while use of static content,

I think , some of the functions of jQuery like `next()`, `siblings()`, `clone()`, `appendTo` are not working. so, I'm trying to find equivalent code of above code with typescript with `Renderer` and `ElementRef` but I am stuck.

here is the component in which I'm using slider

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterContentInit,ElementRef, AfterViewInit, Renderer,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable,Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {QuoteService} from 'app/services/quote.service';
import { asEnumerable } from 'linq-es2015';
declare var $: any;
export class Inclusion
{
    public Help: string;
    public EventType: string;
    public Category: string;
    public Header: string;
    public DaysVisit: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'inclusions',
  templateUrl: './inclusions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inclusions.component.css']
})
export class InclusionsComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('myCarousel') el: ElementRef;
  public inclusions:any;  
  public inclusionList:Inclusion[];  
  public allCat:any;
  public disp_obj =[];
  public test;
  public Incl = [];
  constructor(private quoteService:QuoteService, private renderer:Renderer) {
    this.getInclusion();
   }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log(this.el);
      this.renderer.setElementClass(
        this.el.nativeElement,'active',true,
      )
  }
  getInclusion(){
    this.quoteService.getInclusion()
    .subscribe(
      inclusions=> {
        //this.inclusions = inclusions.resultData;
        this.inclusionList = inclusions.resultData.Inclusions;        
        this.Incl = asEnumerable(this.inclusionList).GroupBy(x => x.Category,  x => x,
         (key, b) =>          
         { return { 
           Category: key ,Services: asEnumerable(b).ToArray() }
            })
        .ToArray();

        console.log(this.Incl);
      },
      response => {
       if (response.status == 404) {
          }
      }
    )
  }

}
```

**component html:**

```
 <div class="inclusions_detail_carousel">
      <div class="carousel-indicators">                 
      </div>
      <!--New Carousel-->
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="well">
            <div id="myCarousel" #myCarousel class="carousel fdi-Carousel slide">
               <div class="carousel-indicators">
                 <a class="left carousel-control" href="#eventCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="icon-prev"></span></a>
                 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#eventCarousel" data-slide="next"> <span class="icon-next"></span></a>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel fdi-Carousel slide" id="eventCarousel" data-interval="0">
               <div class="carousel-inner onebyone-carosel">
                  <div class="item active"  *ngFor="let item of Incl">
                     <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="inclusions_bx_detail">
                           <div class="inclusions_bx_detail_title">
                              <div class="inclusions_bx_detail_title_icon">
                                 <img src="images/inclusions_icon1.jpg" alt="">
                              </div>
                              <h3>hotel stay information</h3>
                              <span>Accomodation And Dining</span>
                           </div>
                           <div class="inclusions_detail_img">
                              <img src="images/inclusions_img1.jpg" alt="">
                           </div>
                           <div class="inclusions_detail_img_info scrollbox3">
                              <div class="inclusions_detail_img_info_in">
                                 <img src="images/inclusions_img_icon1.png" alt="">
                                 <span>2 Nights in Pattaya (Day 1, 2)</span>
                              </div>
                              <div class="inclusions_detail_img_info_in">
                                 <img src="images/inclusions_img_icon1.png" alt="">
                                 <span>2 Nights in Bangkok (Day 3, 4)</span>
                              </div>
                              <div class="inclusions_detail_img_info_in">
                                 <img src="images/inclusions_img_icon1.png" alt="">
                                 <span>4 ABFs (Day 1, 2, 3 ,4)</span>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!--New Carousel-->
</div>
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use pure javascript?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect jquery should also work here

Comment: You may not use JQuery with angular but you can use javascript I think

Comment: @Mr_Perfect Jquery is not a problem while I use static images and content, but when I try to use response from API it doesn't work

Comment: Since the jquery code will access the DOM, call the jquey functions in a differentl ifecycle hook, like -  `AfterContentInit`

Comment: @Abrar well I tried with `ngAfterContentInit()` and also `ngAfterViewInit()`. it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed jquery code was loading before the API call get response for slider,

setting `timeout` done the job

```
setTimeout(() => {
       $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 10000
    })
    $('.fdi-Carousel .item').each(function () {
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

        if (next.next().length > 0) {
            next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
        else {
            $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
    });

}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not discouraged to use JQuery with Angular 2+. You can do it all you want.

What do you mean by saying static and dynamic content ?

Comment: I have tried with jquery but somehow it is not working with dynamic content,
by dynamic content I mean, the response I get from API call and from that I need to display images and content in slider

Comment: I see, then maybe you should post your code that loads the data, and also the code that shows this data.

Comment: Well for starters, you put the active class on each item of your carousel. You could try to change that. I'm looking at other problems, wait a bit

Comment: I don't see any other problems, but do the carousel works with custom html content ? Carousel are usually used for pictures, and I've never tried to use custom content with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147339/discussion-between-nikhil-radadiya-and-trichetriche).

Comment: `setTimeout()` did the job